# 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll?

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, stack-overflow

I had a main thread acting as the job dispatcher. It query terms from a database and dispatch these terms for the async Web I/O. When the web response arrives, the ThreadPool will dispatch a thread to process that response and save to DB.

The StackOverflowException happens in the main thread. Which use entity framework to get a bunch of terms from DB. Code as below.

Currently, I am wondering this: when I use the BeginGetResponse() method to generate work items for thread pool, where are the work items placed? in the main thread's stack? could this be the cause of the StackOverflow? If so, should I slow down how fast the work items are generated??

Is there any way to:

- Identify which thread's stack is overflow?
- What's the content of the overflowed stack?

  ```
  while(!jobDone)
  {
      while(availableBatchQuota<=0)
      {
          polling = true;
          Thread.Sleep(pollingInterval);
          Console.Write("\rPolling...");
      }
      if (polling)
      {
          Console.WriteLine();
          polling = false;
      }

      //At least 1 quota is available
      if (terms.Any())  <=========StackOverflow exception here!
      {
          Interlocked.Decrement(ref availableBatchQuota);
          SearchTermsDistinct term = terms.Take(1).ToList()[0];
          ContextlessTerm term2 = new ContextlessTerm();
          term2.Term = term.Term;
          term2.TermId = term.Term_ID;
          SearchAsync(term2, 1);
          terms = terms.Skip(1);
      }
      else
          jobDone = true;
  }
  ```

--

```
public static void SearchAsync(ContextlessTerm term, Int32 pageIndex)
{
    String processedTerm = TermPreProcess.Process(term.Term);
    if (processedTerm.Length == 0) return; // if the term is empty, we shouldn't search it.
    Console.WriteLine("Searching term: {0}", processedTerm);
    String query = String.Format(queryString, processedTerm, (pageIndex - 1) * 10 + 1);
    //Console.WriteLine(query);
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(query);
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
    {
        List<mySearchResultClass> resultsOnePage = null;
        using (WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(ar))
        {
            resultsOnePage = GetResultURLsForOnePage(response.GetResponseStream());
            Int32 rank = 1;
            foreach (var result in resultsOnePage)
            {
                result.Rank = (pageIndex - 1) * 10 + rank;
                rank++;
            }
        }
        lock (dbSync)
        {
            SaveToDB(term, resultsOnePage);
        }
        if (pageIndex < maxSearchPages && resultsOnePage.Count() == 10) SearchAsync(term, pageIndex + 1);// relay race!
        else
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref availableBatchQuota);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref progress);
            //Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            //Console.WriteLine("Done searching term: {0}", processedTerm);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: Available: {1}\tProgress:{2:f3}%", DateTime.Now.ToString(), availableBatchQuota, progress * 100.0 / totalTerms);
            //Console.ResetColor();
        }
    }, null);
}
```

### ADD 1

Below is what I see in the DEBUG->Threads window. It seems to be the main thread in trouble.

[image]

### ADD 2

The stack trace.

[image]

### ADD 3

I just re-run my application, this time the exception happens at the same place, but the DLL in trouble changes to **EntityFramework.dll**. Too strange...

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Comment: Is `terms` at `if (terms.Any())` an `IEnumerable<>`? If so, it could be a side effect of LINQ lazy evaluation. The whole sequence may be getting re-evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your stack trace, it's a bit difficult to provide a definitive answer, but I think sticking to the basics leads me to believe the source of your StackOverflow is the

```
SearchAsync(ContextlessTerm term, Int32 pageIndex)
```

which calls itself:

```
if (pageIndex < maxSearchPages && resultsOnePage.Count() == 10) SearchAsync(term, pageIndex + 1);// relay race!
```

Have you analyzed your code to know how deep  your recursion goes on average?  Does it always hit a StackOverflow, or only under certain circumstances?

Comment: I tried to check the exception details in the DEBUG run, but it just says *"Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state."*

Comment: It would be helpful to know what program language this is.  It looks like C#?

Comment: Yes, C#. And also, I set condition for the recursion, it's unlikely for an endless recursion.

Comment: @smwikipedia: not the exception details, the stack trace is needed. Just show the contents of the stack debugger window.

Comment: @PMF I added the stack trace to my question. But it seems not much helpful.

Comment: @smwikipedia: That really _is_ weird. A stackoverflow exception with an almost empty stack *confused*.